# How can I do Parallel computing using c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to evaluate about 100k results and then save in a list because then I represent this on a chart.

But using only one thread is too long and I decided to use multithreading but I don't know anything about this.

This is the function that I use with a single thread:

```
for(int i=min;i<max;i++)
{
    list.Add(evaluate(expression, i));
}
```

I would like to do something like that but with multiple threads.

Comment: Well what research have you done so far? Have you looked at Parallel LINQ? The Task Parallel Library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at the  [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx)  and [Parallel Programming in .NET Framework 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/06/01/parallel-programming-in-net-framework-4-getting-started.aspx)

> The purpose of the TPL is to make developers more productive by
>   simplifying the process of adding parallelism and concurrency to
>   applications. The TPL scales the degree of concurrency dynamically to
>   most efficiently use all the processors that are available. In
>   addition, the TPL handles the partitioning of the work, the scheduling
>   of threads on the ThreadPool, cancellation support, state management,
>   and other low-level details. By using TPL, you can maximize the
>   performance of your code while focusing on the work that your program
>   is designed to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this could help you.

```
var max = 100;
var min = 20;
var list = new MyResult[max - min];

Parallel.For(min, max, i =>
{
    list[i - min] = evaluate(expression, i);
});
```

Note that whatever `evaluate` does needs to be thread safe.

Comment: yes evaluate is thread safe. I have another question for you: if iI want make a streo!=1 in Parallel.For how can I do? It's possible?

Comment: @user220255 Could you be a little more clear on that question.

Comment: Sorry. Evaluate(string, double) is thread safe method. If I want do a step!=1 in Parallel.For how can I do?

Comment: @Tinwor `step!=1`? Maybe you need to open a need question or update the existing one.

Comment: @Tinwor: You can pass for example `evaluate(expression, i*2)`, which will count by two (`i` counts by one so `i*2` counts by two)